# react-i18next old useSuspense warning

Tags: reactjs, react-i18next

While running the react app There is a warning appeared as I mentioned below

```
react-i18next:: It seems you are still using the old wait option, you may migrate to the new useSuspense behaviour.
```

How can I clear this warning?

Comment: Try updating your React version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

None of the suggested options worked for me, as `react: { wait: true }` is deprecated and `react { useSuspense: true }` didn't do anything.

What did work for me was placing the following in the same file that was causing me grief (which uses the `Trans` component):

```js
  const { t } = useTranslation();
  const noop = t('noopkey', "do the thing");
```

why this works:

From the documentation for [useTranslate](https://react.i18next.com/latest/usetranslation-hook):

> The useTranslation hook will trigger a Suspense if not ready (eg.
> pending load of translation files). You can set useSuspense to false
> if prefer not using Suspense.

Hope it helps someone else.

Answer (score 2):

Check your i18next options and remove the wait option...

Answer (score 0):

If you are not using Next.js with SSR, then, just replace `wait: true` with `useSuspense: true`

Sources:

- https://github.com/freeCodeCamp/freeCodeCamp/issues/41211#issuecomment-783702803
- https://github.com/freeCodeCamp/freeCodeCamp/issues/41211#issuecomment-836606503